# How to cycle through table rows programmatically

Tags: tabulator

I need to process the data from a table, what is the best way to step through the rows of a table programmatically?

Comment: I think you could get your answer more quickly if you could elaborate your case and add some code examples.

Comment: Way too broad. What language, what framework? Where does the code run, in a browser, on a server, in a batch job? Where does the data come from, e.g., database or csv file or something else? Most importantly, what have you tried and what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Robert http://tabulator.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const rows = table.getRows();
console.log('rows', rows);
```

Returns an array and you can iterate over it